# Change jquery variable for each instance it's used on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting up a page that has multiple links to different documents. Since the names of the links match the documents they are linked to, I thought I would write a script that takes the inner html of anything underlined and generates a link tag around it and inputs each particular link name in the link.

The script I wrote runs fine except it only runs once and updates all links with one identical link for each. Is there a way I can make it take each instance and change them individually?

Sorry if I've butchered my explaination!

Here is my current code:

```
<u>Link1</u>
<u>Link2</u>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
innerU = $("u").html();
$("u").html("<a href=mywebsite.com/" + innerU + ".pdf>" + innerU + "</a>");
</script>
```

Comment: You should Google it before posting question - first link for `jquery for each` will lead you where you should have started.

Comment: @KonradGadzina if you read his code, I think he didn't know about jQuery's `.each()` method. If you dont know what it's called, you cannot search for it.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen I'm not suggesting that he knew about this method, that would be stupid. ^^ If you read a title of this question, you see that he knew how to form good question, so it's simply about getting keywords from the question and googling. The phrase I quoted in first comment was taken from the question's title. I know there are times when you don't even know what to search for, but this title suggested me that it was not the case now. No offence, I simply think that people should try harder before posting question and learn how to search the web.

Comment: @KonradGadzina You made a good point sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to apply the transformation you want to each `<u>` element in your page. Something like this:

```
$("u").each(function() {
    var innerU = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("<a href='mywebsite.com/" + innerU + ".pdf'>" + innerU + "</a>");
});
```

EDIT : added quote around href value to produce valid HTML. Thanks [Kolink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) for noticing.

Comment: @user1524879 > No problem, don't forget to accept an answer. Especially Kolink's answer which is way better.

Comment: Produces invalid HTML.

Comment: @Kolink > Nice catch, I focused on showing the each and didn't properly checked the produced HTML

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
(function() { // create a closure to avoid leaking variables
   var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("u"), l = tags.length, i, t, a;
   for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
      a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = "http://mywebsite.com/"+tags[i].firstChild.nodeValue+".pdf";
      a.appendChild(tags[i].firstChild);
      tags[i].appendChild(a);
   }
})();
```

This is better for several reasons:

1. It's vanilla JavaScript, so it runs hundreds of times faster
2. It uses a closure so as to avoid variables polluting the global scope
3. It uses DOM methods rather than `innerHTML` (which is what jQuery's `.html()` uses)
4. It treats the text node as text, which is important if you have HTML entities such as `&eacute;` in there.

Comment: Curious why you state that it's better to insert via DOM methods rather than using innerHTML...

Comment: Because `innerHTML` has to be parsed, processed and inserted. It destroys any references to the old nodes, including (and especially) event listeners. It doesn't *really* apply here, but in general it is best to avoid `innerHTM`.

Comment: Good answer, I would love to see a _perf_ illustrating it being a "hundred times faster" though, that's a bold claim

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Tried to make one, but the jQuery version kept crashing the browser. Probably just me not using jsperf correctly, thouhg.

Comment: That's ok, I'll try and make one, thanks for the attempt

Comment: @Kolink -- Whoops... read that reversed... thought you were saying that `innerHTML` was faster than DOM methods... my bad...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -- Someone already created one a while ago... http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-dom-methods

Comment: @natlee75 thanks, didn't see that, I just made this http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-native-dom-node-insert

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
$("u").each(function () {

    var innerU = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("<a href=mywebsite.com/" + innerU + ".pdf>" + innerU + "</a>");

});
```

Although, there is a lot 'wrong' with your code. For example the use of the `<u>` tag to generate links? Why not use anhors directly and dynamically set their href attribute like so:

```
<a href="#" class='coollink'>Link1</a>
<a href="#" class='coollink'>Link2</a>

<script>
$("a.coollink").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("href", "//mywebsite.com/" + $(this).html() + ".pdf");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method of JQuery.

```
$('u').each(function(){
    innerU = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("<a href=mywebsite.com/" + innerU + ".pdf>" + innerU + "</a>");
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/me4Ue/)**

Comment: -1 for re-posting a solution that was already here and failing to post good working code. Should use `var` when declaring new variable names.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen Oh, should blame it on slow net connection, didn't see other answers before posting or would have just upvoted Kolink's solution which is much better.